# css menu - active main menu item

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I am using a CSS menu that is provided by the WPML package.

I would like to have the active main-menu-item to stay blue when it is active.

what I have done in the past is apply the color to .li selected_page

the problem is that all the sub-menu items also have this tag applied, which means that in most browsers (strangely not the current firefox) whenever it is active all the menu items including the sub-menu items are blue.

Does anyone see a way to apply the blue color to the active main menu item so that it stays blue when it has been clicked? Thanks!

-EDIT- after all the help:
as usually the solution is a sum-total of all of your help :) I finally made it by using the following code:

```
#menu-wrap li.selected_page a { color: #1983AF; } 
#menu-wrap ul li.selected_page ul>li>a { color: #000; }
#menu-wrap ul li.selected_page ul>li>a:hover { color: #1983AF};
```

Comment: Thank you for all your answers!

by using:
    #menu-wrap ul li.selected_page a {
      color: #1983AF;
   }
I can change the color of the menu item. The problem is however, that it changes the color of -every- sub-menu item as well.

I love the idea of :first-child, however i can not get it to work. I have tried to apply it in every way I could think of but the only result i get is either all black or all blue... :(

Comment: Updated my answer to fix that bit. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is inheritance - your style

```
#menu-wrap li.selected_page {
    color: #1983AF;
}
```

is being overwritten by

```
#menu-wrap ul a {
    color: #333333;
}
```

Try updating the first example to read:

```
#menu-wrap ul li.selected_page a {
    color: #1983AF;
}
```

That should force it to take precedence in the CSS. Hope this helps! Best of luck.

EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:

To get the sub-items *not* appearing in blue, add this - changing #000 to whatever color you wish:

```
#menu-wrap ul li.selected_page a ul a {
    color: #000;
}
```

And if you want a different color for selected sub-items, just add the color to this selector (already in your stylesheet):

```
#menu-wrap li.selected_subpage
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try the ">" CSS selector, something like "#cms-nav-top-menu > li.selected_page {color: blue;}"

However, this won't work in old browsers.

See http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Answer (score 1):

```
li.selected_page a:first-child
{
    color:#1983AF;
}
```

[CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

Comment: i have the feeling this should work, however it doesn't :(
If I apply it as you suggested everything stays black,
If I apply it to "li.selected_page a:first-child" then everything becomes blue.. I dont understand why

Comment: @j00ls lol oops.  The exact spec is *"**E:first-child** an E element, first child of its parent*". so that makes sense.  It's not the nodes first child but if the node is a first child.

Comment: i tried the a:first-child idea yesterday (i looked it up) but it didnt help. Still a great tip though and I might be able to use it some time in the future. :)